# Gutenberg: How to mix dynamic and static output?

Tags: customization, block-editor

Gutenbergs handbook (https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/creating-dynamic-blocks/) suggests to `return null` in the `save()` function for dynamic blocks.

But what if I only want parts of my block to be dynamic and others to be static?

Even if you save content statically in the `save()` function, it get's completely overwritten by the dynamic content

I am wondering how to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: For those interested: I also posted this question / proposition on gutenbergs github issues. https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7331 – It is so hard to get information / experts to help with this new technology.